# Submitting values from dynamically named radio inputs to database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, dynamic, input

I'm an amateur at best with PHP, but I can blag my way through at a slow pace.
In the code below I'm trying to get the values of some dynamically produced radio buttons and then submitting the details to the database.

I'm having partial success as the database is being updated, but it's only the last date. e.g. The code below generates radio buttons for 2016-03-01, 2016-03-02, 2016-03-03 and 2016-03-04. If I select 'closed' on all of the radio buttons and submit it only changes for the last date in the database.

There's probably a much easier way to do this. But from Googling around this was the code I managed to scrape together with my limited knowledge.

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

```
<form action="" id="open_closed" method="post">
<?php
global $wpdb;
$startdate       = '2016-03-01';
$nextdate        = '2016-03-04';
$get_month_dates = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_vgs_attendance WHERE date >= '$startdate' AND date <= '$nextdate' ");
foreach ($get_month_dates as $month_dates) {
$individual_date = $month_dates->date;
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $individual_date . '" id="' . $individual_date . '" value="0">Open</input>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $individual_date . '" id="' . $individual_date . '" value="1">Closed</input>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="date-' . $individual_date . '" id="date-' . $individual_date . '" value="' . $individual_date . '"></input> - ' . $individual_date . '<br><br>';
}

?>
<input name="open_closed" type="submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['open_closed'])) {
global $wpdb;
foreach ($get_month_dates as $month_dates) {
    $individual_date = $month_dates->date;
    $name            = $individual_date;
    $open            = $_POST[$name];
    $date            = $_POST['date-' . $individual_date . ''];
}

$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_vgs_attendance SET closed = '$open' WHERE date = '$date'");

}
```

Comment: You're giving the same ID to both buttons in each group. IDs are supposed to be unique. Are you sure the buttons even need to have IDs? They probably only need names.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" id="open_closed" method="post">
<?php
global $wpdb;
$startdate       = '2016-03-01';
$nextdate        = '2016-03-04';
$get_month_dates = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_vgs_attendance WHERE date >= '$startdate' AND date <= '$nextdate' ");
foreach ($get_month_dates as $month_dates) {
$individual_date = $month_dates->date;
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $individual_date . '" id="' . $individual_date . '" value="0">Open</input>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $individual_date . '" id="' . $individual_date . '" value="1">Closed</input>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="date-' . $individual_date . '" id="date-' . $individual_date . '" value="' . $individual_date . '"></input> - ' . $individual_date . '<br><br>';
}

?>
<input name="open_closed" type="submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['open_closed'])) {
global $wpdb;
foreach ($get_month_dates as $month_dates) {
    $individual_date = $month_dates->date;
    $name            = $individual_date;
    $open            = $_POST[$name];
    $date            = $_POST['date-' . $individual_date . ''];

    $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_vgs_attendance SET closed = '$open' WHERE date = '$date'");
}

}
```

Just put UPDATE query inside foreach loop.